# Webview content not set properly when device is rotated in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application wherein I have a web view where I am displaying my html page inside the webview. When the content of html page goes beyond the frame of web view I am passing the rest of the content outside the frame of web view to new page. This is working properly.

When the web view is launched in portrait mode and when I rotate the screen to landscape the web view content gets displayed properly. But when I scroll the content of web view to next page and then rotate the webview then rotation is not working properly. Half content of first page and half content of second page is displayed on the web view.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    backbuttonclick=NO;
    textFontSize=100;
    pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
    pagecontrol = [[StyledPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(208, 959, 358, 36)];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        //Landscape
        viewstatus =@"landscape";

        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px;margin-top:20px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", 680.0f, 1024.0f];
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        pagecontrol.frame =CGRectMake(300, 710, 150, 36);

    }else{

        //Portrait
        viewstatus =@"portrait";
        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px;margin-top:20px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", 905.0f, 768.0f];
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        pagecontrol.frame =CGRectMake(208, 959, 358, 36);

    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action: @selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2 ;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap] ;
    UIScrollView* sv = nil;
    for(UIView* v in self.webview.subviews){
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class] ]){
            sv = (UIScrollView*) v;
            [sv setZoomScale:9.0f animated:YES];
            sv.bounces = NO;
        }
    }

    [pagecontrol setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [pagecontrol addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:pagecontrol];
    webview.scrollView.delegate=self;
    webview.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    webview.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataObject];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

In the web view did finish load I have written css to break html content into pages if the content size is created then the view size:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    CGFloat height = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight"] floatValue];

    if (height<960)
    {
        pagecount=1;
    }
    if (height>960&&height<1920)
    {
        pagecount=2;
    }
    if (height>1920&&height<2880)
    {
        pagecount=3;
    }
    if (height>1024)
    {
        NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

        NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
        "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
        "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
        "} else {"
        "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
        "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
        "}"
        "}";
        NSString *insertRule1 ;

        if([viewstatus isEqualToString:@"landscape"])
        {
            insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px;margin-top:10px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap:0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')",
680.0f, 1024.0f];
            [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        }
        if([viewstatus isEqualToString:@"portrait"])
        {

            insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px;margin-top:10px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')",
905.0f, 768.0f];
            [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        }

        NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
        NSString *setHighlightColorRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('highlight', 'background-color: yellow;')"];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setHighlightColorRule];
    }

    int totalWidth = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] intValue];
    int hi = (int)((float)totalWidth/webview.bounds.size.width);
    self.pagecontrol.numberOfPages=hi;
    self.pagecontrol.hidesForSinglePage=YES;
    [self.pagecontrol setPageControlStyle:PageControlStyleStrokedCircle];
     }
```

This is my scroll method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed)
    {
        self.webview.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.webview.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.webview.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1;
        NSLog(@"%d",page);
        self.pagecontrol.currentPage = page;
        [webview.superview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
        webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
       return;
    }

}
```

This is my rotation method:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == 1 || toInterfaceOrientation == 2)
    {
        viewstatus =@"portrait";
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pagecontrol];
        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px;margin-top:20px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", 905.0f, 768.0f];
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        [webview.superview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
        webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        pagecontrol.frame =CGRectMake(230, 959, 600, 36);

    }
    if(toInterfaceOrientation == 3 || toInterfaceOrientation == 4)
    {
        viewstatus =@"landscape";
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pagecontrol];
        NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px;margin-top:10px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", 680.0f, 1024.0f];
        [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];
        [webview.superview setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
        webview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
       pagecontrol.frame =CGRectMake(300, 710, 150, 36);

    }

}
```

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: @NiravPatel i have edited my question.Please check

Comment: oops,,you have written really much code..now tell me have you given taken webview in XIB?

Comment: @NiravPatel yes i have taken web view in xib

Comment: Hi @NiravPatel have checked my question

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you have taken webview in xib , then why dont you make it autosizing?like below...
[image]